# Nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-forms

I have the following data where the first column is `ID`, second column is `category`, third column is `items` and fourth column is `price`. I am trying to find each ID's spend sum by category (column 2 from left): I've included a sample output below.

However, I am stuck on the `elif` statement and says it has `keyError: 'A'`.  I really do not know what is wrong.

sample output:

```
Spending by B
fuel - 19.60 
grocery - 11.42
```

Input:

```
A|groceries|cereal|15.50
A|groceries|milk|14.75
A|tobacco|cigarettes|25.00
A|fuel|gasoline|54.90
B|fuel|propane|19.60
B|groceries|apple|11.42
C|tobacco|cigarettes|25.00
```

code:

```
for line in fileinput.input(fo1):
    #print line
    line =str.rstrip(line)
    line = line.split('|')
    print line[0],line[1]
    (name,category,items,price)=line

    if line[0] in report2 and line[1] in report2:
        report2[line[0]][line[1]] += float(price)    
    elif line[1] in report2[line[0]]:
        report2[line[0]][line[1]]+=float(price)
    else:
        report2[line[0]][line[1]]=float(price)

print report2.keys
print report2.items()
```

Comment: report2[line[0]] is really report2['A'] which doesn't exist yet!  First, check if `line[0] in report2`, then you can continue.

Comment: It may make your life a lot easier to use the `csv` module instead of trying to parse the input manually. If that's not appropriate (e.g., it's a homework problem and you were told not to use it), that's fine, but otherwise, it's just extra code that could be the problem and therefore has to be debugged.

Comment: `str.rstrip(line)` is normally spelled `line.rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to access values in `report2` that you haven't created yet.

It's pretty much the same problem you'd get with a variable. Imagine you had this code:

```
i = 1
if i == 1:
    a += 2
else:
    a = 2
```

You can't do `a += 2` because there is no value there.

So to fix this, you need to deal with the case where you're seeing a key for the first time. You can use `defaultdict` instead of `dict`, or the `setdefault` method, or an explicit `in` check, or a `try`, but usually one of the first two will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `collections.defaultdict` and `collections.Counter` here:

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter
dic = defaultdict(lambda: Counter())
with open('abc1') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, item, _, price = line.split('|')
        dic[k][item] += float(price)

for k, v in dic.items():
    print "Spending by",k
    for item, val in v.items():
        print "{} - {}".format(item, val)
    print
```

**Output:**

```
Spending by A
fuel - 54.9
groceries - 30.25
tobacco - 25.0

Spending by C
tobacco - 25.0

Spending by B
fuel - 19.6
groceries - 11.42
```

Answer (score 0):

How about Numpy:

```
import numpy

# data prep
examplerows= ['A|groceries|cereal|15.50', 'A|groceries|milk|14.75', 'A|tobacco|cigarettes|25.00', 'A|fuel|gasoline|54.90', 
            'B|fuel|propane|19.60', 'B|groceries|apple|11.42', 'C|tobacco|cigarettes|25.00']

examplerows = [r.split('|') for r in examplerows]

# summarize using numpy
data = numpy.array(examplerows)
categories = numpy.unique(data[:, 0])
groups = [data[data[:, 0] == c, 3] for c in categories]
value_groups = [numpy.array([float(i) for i in g]).sum() for g in groups]

print dict(zip(categories, value_groups))
```